# Dynamics Ax EDT Filter

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Hi I'm sorry for my English

I made an EDT that relation with table field and use EDT on StringEdit for make lookup.

Here is my problem. When I use EDT on StringEdit All records coming into but i want to get only 'CostCenter' valued ones

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If `CostCenter` is an enum value, then you could resolved this with a *conditional table relation*. Documentation for these relations can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/conditional-table-relations).

When this is not the case you can provide a *custom lookup* for the form field. An example is also available in the documentation, see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/how-to-add-a-lookup-form-to-a-control).

Answer (score -1):

If the proble is that you dont want to see more than one specific colum in the table you could modify the autolookup group in the table.